# How to list GUI applications on windows

Tags: windows, qt

On linux I can parse the xdg application directories for *.desktop files. Done. 
Is there any way like this on windows. wmic.exe is not an option, since the list is incomplete an contains elements irrelevant to the user.

I want to list installed applications, meaning all those listed under Start/Programs. And not e.g. cl.exe which is somewhere in C:/Programs/...

A qt solution is preferred but not mandatory.

Comment: You want to get list of currently running "GUI" apps? First question - what you mean by "GUI application"? On windows there are 2 type of application subsystems: `console` and `windows`. Everything that is not a `console` - is `windows` application.

Comment: I mean executables which are no unistallers, no console apps, no helperprograms. Primaryly those in the start menu.

Comment: You mean applications, that are installed in windows with installers? They may be a console applications too, or services :). You can't detect it. You need to clarify your criterias.

Comment: This article describes how to get the list of windows that make it into the "alt-tab" list, though it does mention not to rely on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx

Comment: Its hard to describe. I want to code a kickstarter. Imagine which apps you want to start with it. Indeed no services, uninstallers and consoleapps. Lets assume those in the startmenu for now.

Comment: the startmenu is just a folder with subfolders, you can iterate it and list all the shortcuts you find that point to an executable and don't have "uninstall" in the name

Comment: Windows doesn't have anything quite like desktop files on Linux.  The closest thing is the list of uninstallable applications which you can find in the registry.